# Как вставить значения из формы в word файлик?

Tags: php, ms-word, javascript

На страничке форма, заполнив ее, необходимо что бы значения вставились в word документ и он либо открылся либо начался качаться к клиенту.
Как и на чем это можно реализовать? php или js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@artyom](/users/7203/artyom)](/users/7203/artyom) ты что пишешь?

> это можно сделать при помощи методов
> GET и POST.

Это неправильно, этим ты никуда ничего не вставишь. Это просто метода отправки данных и не более того.

ТС вот тебе [ссылка](http://demura.su/articles/php/sozdaem_doc_fajl_cherez_php/) ( не пиар :) )

Comment: Только это будет документ MS Office 2007, у старших версий был бинарный формат

Comment: а кто говорит про старые версии?

Я вообще людям в глаза говорю что IE6-полное Г! и хрен оспоришь!

Так что 2007 лучше чем 2010, там вообще архив зиповский, нафига спрашивается.

Comment: Нет, 2010 лучше , чем 2007.

Comment: и чем лучше? быстрее обрабатывается нажатие на кнопки и 3 новых шрифта в комплекте? Визуально для офисного работника они вообще ничем не отличаются.

Comment: 2 @beardog

>вот и выросло поколение, которое не помнит великую войну форматов >офисных документов

вопрос зачем мне это помнить, когда я давно отказался от этого? Бред, полный бред не относящийся к вопросу вообще! 

"Зачем жить в каменном веке, когда есть железо и порох" (с)

Comment: Просто уточнил одну маленькую деталь, и ни в коем случае не хотел вас задеть :) Мне меня эта тема в свое время казалась очень  важной и заметной, отсюда некоторое удивление